# Regarding Messages in Veins

Tags: omnet++, veins

I want to send a message as soon as the vehicle starts. For this I am using the self-message technique. I send a self-message and in the `handleMessage` method after receiving the self-message I send the `WaveShortMessage` which I want to send.

Is this the correct way to send the message?

Also I want to know the difference between a cMessage and a `WaveShortMessage`.

Comment: Is this question answered?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the correct way of doing it as you can see for example in [`BaseWaveApplLayer`](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.5/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/BaseWaveApplLayer.cc).

A [`cMessage`](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:msgs:cmessage) is OMNeT++' base class for messages whereas a [`WaveShortMessage`](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.5/src/veins/modules/messages/WaveShortMessage.msg) is a special message type for the WAVE-Stack which inherits from `cMessage` when the corresponding header file is generated.